# Encrypting FIrefox snap user data

Tags: firefox, 22.04, encryption, snap

With the regular firefox package, I was able to move my `~/.mozilla` folder to a eCryptFS `Private` directory and symlink it to encrypt all my profile data (cookies, history, etc) and make this transparent to Firefox.

Now, with the snap package being the default installation method for Firefox, I'm not really sure where the data is stored... `~/snap/firefox/common` appears to be mounted from `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_XXXX.snap`, which is some kind of file system on its own managed entirely by snapd, so how am I supposed to encrypt it now (other than encrypt full disk)?

Comment: Workaround: Replace snap firefox with apt https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi yeah, that's what I've been using so far. But the question still remains for other apps, e.g. Telegram. The `telegram-desktop` in Ubuntu repos is outdated and keeps crashing, and I want to install the snap version. But I can't move its snap data to e.g. `~/Private` directory because snap doesn't work with symlinks. Basically, the only solution is to encrypt the whole `/home` directory...

Comment: For Telegram, I use the telegram binary from https://telegram.org/dl/desktop/linux (download, and extract and run it - it will save its shortcut in the menu), which automatically updates itself if some update is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application is indeed inside a compressed file in `/var/lib/snapd/snaps`, like all snaps. It's mounted underneath `/snap/firefox` as a read-only mount.

Your personal data is indeed in your home under `~/snap/firefox`. I haven't tried moving that folder to an eCryptFS location, but it may be possible. Just be aware that the Firefox snap is strictly confined so there's limited locations you can put the eCryptFS and it still be accessible to Firefox. Specifically don't put it outside `$HOME` and don't put it in a hidden folder in your `$HOME`.

Comment: Sadly, moving `~/snap` to `~/Private/snap` and then symlinking it does not work - all snaps fail to start because symlinks are not allowed in snap data dir path apparently. I ended up installing Firefox from the DEB package provided by Mozilla Team PPA.